# How to recover spatial coordinates that correspond to specific value of a raster file?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, raster-calculator

I want to recover the spatial locations that correspond to specific one value of my raster file. Is there a  way to do that?

Comment: Please provide us an example of what you are after and perhaps some code showing what you have already tried. Your statement "correspond to one value of my raster" is not adequate as we do not know if this "one value" represents numerous cells or just one or if you are using interger or float data. Please also read our FAQ on the sites intent and how to ask a reproducible question.

Comment: I have a raster file that takes few values , (0,100,1000), what I want is to extract the spatial locations of all the cells in my raster file that have the value 100. Or recover the cells numbers satisfying this condition.

Answer (score 5):

If you have ample memory to read the raster into RAM you can use `which`. We will first create a raster with 3 values (0, 100, 1000) per your description.

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=100, ncol=100)
  r[] <- sample(c(0,100,1000), ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
```

Now we can use `which` to identify the position of cells meeting the query and `xyFromCell` to return the associated [X,Y] coordinates.

```
xy <- xyFromCell(r, which(r[] == 100)) 
  head(xy)
```

Answer (score 4):

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=3, nrow=3, vals=c(0,100,1000,1000,100,0,0,100,1000))
```

You can do:

```
rasterToPoints( match(r, 100))
#     x   y layer
#[1,] 0  60     1
#[2,] 0   0     1
#[3,] 0 -60     1
```

or

```
as.data.frame( match(r, 100), xy=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE)
```

or, for multiple values

```
rasterToPoints( match(r, c(0, 100)))
#        x   y layer
#[1,] -120  60     1
#[2,]    0  60     2
#[3,]    0   0     2
#[4,]  120   0     1
#[5,] -120 -60     1
#[6,]    0 -60     2
```

Where the value in the third column (the name of the layer) matches the order used in `match`. That is 1 = 0 and 2 = 100.

You can use `Which` if you only care for a single value.

```
cells <- Which(r==100, cells=TRUE)
#[1] 2 5 8
 
xyFromCell(r, cells)
#     x   y
#[1,] 0  60
#[2,] 0   0
#[3,] 0 -60
```

I prefer `Which(r == 100)` over Jeffrey Evans' `which(r[] == 100` because using `r[]` is not memory-safe (it forces all values into memory).

An alternative for one or multiple values you can use `subs` or `reclassify`, again followed by `rasterToPoints`

```
s <- subs(r, data.frame(from=c(0,100), to=c(0,100)))
rasterToPoints(s)
#        x   y  to
#[1,] -120  60   0
#[2,]    0  60 100
#[3,]    0   0 100
#[4,]  120   0   0
#[5,] -120 -60   0
#[6,]    0 -60 100
```